# Do we need a reset tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Today's justify-your-existence question is directed at [reset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset). There are three questions with this tag:

- [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27865/8366), about syncing a new PS3 controller, where the context is "resetting the controller";
- [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/535/8366), about clearing save-game data on a used DS game, where the context is "resetting the game";
- and [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322/8366), asking about when weekly drop limits on TF2 reset.

As near as I can tell, [reset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset) is a bad example of a meta tag. The only thing these questions seem to have in common is the word "reset". Can anyone speak up for this brave little tag, or should it be removed with prejudice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone ahead and retagged all three. So long, [reset](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset)!